# Authenticate Google Users in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, passport.js

I have a custom Node.js server using Express and PassportJS (for Google OAuth2.0 authentication). I want to build a Chrome extension that will authenticate through my Node.js server, but is still Google OAuth2.0. Additionally, if a user has signed into the website, the Chrome extension should also be signed in. What are steps I should take to accomplish this? I've taken a look at [User Authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) docs but this is what confused me. My auth identity is Google since (client ID, secret are the same), but I'm authenticating through another server.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?